# Как загрузить аватар ВК в `ImageView`?

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Создаю запрос:

```
VKRequest userphoto = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, "photo_100"));
```

Дальше надо результат загрузить в `ImageView`.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь библиотеками типа UIL или Picasso для загрузки и отображения картинок по ссылкам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположу следующий вариант на основе [примера](https://github.com/rokhlin/vk1000): 
есть класс PicassoCache:

```
public class PicassoCache {

private static Picasso picassoInstance = null;

private PicassoCache (Context context) {

    Downloader downloader   = new OkHttpDownloader(context, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(context);
    builder.downloader(downloader);

    picassoInstance = builder.build();
public static Picasso getPicassoInstance (Context context) {

    if (picassoInstance == null) {

        new PicassoCache(context);
        return picassoInstance;
    }

    return picassoInstance;
}
}
```

В fragment_user.xml в этом примере используется ImageView:

```
<ImageView
        style="@style/avatar"
        android:id="@+id/iv_user_avatar" />
```

По ID ***iv_user_avatar*** находим **LoadUserFragment.java**, в котором ищем наш вью:

```
avatar = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.iv_user_avatar);
```

далее используем так:

```
PicassoCache.getPicassoInstance(getContext()).load(curUser.getPhoto50()).into(avatar);
```

Объяснил в общих чертах. Думаю, это должно вам указать где искать ответ.